# Shared value gets (unnecessarily) evaluated multiple times in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749039/automatic-memoizing-in-functional-programming-languages/5752979#5752979) answer which made it sound like when a shared value is evaluated, it is only evaluated once and then the result is stored. For example:

```
x = 2 + 2
y = 2 + x
z = 3 + x
```

Here, `x` is evaluated once and then stored as `4`, and it is never evaluated again? At least that was my assumption. My code has a value that gets re-calculated every time it is referenced. It is a pure value. When would this happen, and how can I force Haskell to remember the value once it is calculated?

Example:

```
x = [1, 1, 2]
count = fst $ getCounts x
```

Here, `count` gets evaluated every time it is referenced.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations? If so, and still seeing this behavior, then you have likely turned off the monomorphism restriction without actually understanding it.

Comment: How do you know it is? While Haskell compilers can optimise however they like and, when it can show the computation is cheap, GHC may duplicate work, I doubt it would happen in a case with a top-level binding like this, unless `getCounts` is very simple indeed.

Comment: ehird: I'm using trace to test. Plus, when a simple piece of code takes 5 minutes, you figure it out :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Daniel Wagner points out, the most likely scenario here is that `count` is not given an explicit type signature, but you've turned the monomorphism restriction off (e.g. with the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` language extension). This means that `count` has a type like

```
count :: (Num a) => a
```

This means that GHC treats `count` like a function (specifically, from the `Num` typeclass dictionary for any type `a`, to an `a`), and so the results are not shared, meaning its value is recomputed on every use.

The best solution is to give count an explicit type signature, e.g.

```
count :: Int
```

You should probably do the same for `x`, too (and, for that matter, all the other top-level definitions in your program).

Comment: Wow, my mind just got blown. No, I don't understand NoMonomorphismRestriction and yes I was using `alias ghci=ghci -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`. It's gone now.

Comment: And no I don't write my own type signatures. Time to start.

Comment: @VladtheImpala the general style guide for Haskell is that you should write type signatures for all top-level bindings.