# Map which must contain all possible keys?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, types

Haskell has multiple data structures like `Map key value`, either using a tree or hash map internally. When using this data structure, it is possible that when doing a lookup, the key will not be present.

In my use case the set of possible keys is finite (technically they are in both `Enum` and `Ord`) and I am only interested in having a map with all keys present.

How to create a map-like data structure that guarantees all keys are present in the map, i.e. it can have a non-partial function `lookup :: Map key value -> key -> value` (possibly with constraints on `key` type, `Ord` or `Hashable` or anything else)? Is there something like this already?

In other words: I want a data structure that can only be queried if all possible keys were inserted. I could use regular `Map` with `fromMaybe`, but I don't want to have to specify default value – I want to guarantee at type level that default value is never needed.

Comment: What value should the map return for a key which you have not manually inserted? If it is the same for every key, you could use ``fromMaybe`` from `Data.Maybe` instead.

Comment: Don't you mean `lookup :: Ord key => Map key value -> key -> value`? You do need the `Ord` constraint...

Comment: @ThreeFx I updated the question with more details.

Comment: @Jubobs yeah, sure, I can do with `Ord` constraint, I don't really card whether it uses that or hashing or any other mechanism.

Comment: It seems to me what you want is just a total `k -> v` function.

Comment: Any reason not to use an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The structure you are looking for is just a function : `Key -> Value`.
You can *insert* (or in fact replace) value with the following

```
insert :: (Key -> Value) -> Key -> Value -> (Key -> Value)
insert f k v k' = if k == k' then v else f k'
```

`keys` and `values` function are trivial to implement (you just need your Key type to be an `Enum`).
The compiler can warn you if a function is partial or not (ultimately, which ever data structure you use, you can't stop someone to insert an `undefined` value).

Comment: Note that after n updates at the same key `k`, the updated function will incur at O(n) penalty to access the value for every other key. Unfortunately, `a->b` is not an ideal "data structure" updates are involved.

Comment: I agree with that. It's not really a data structure and does responds to update really well. However, using a function as argument instead of particular data structure, is good, because the user can then use any data structure if needed.

Answer (score 7):

You should look into a technique known as **memo(ization) tries**.  A memo trie for a function type `A -> B` is a data type that represents a function of that type as a data structure that records all the argument/result combinations.  Some links you may look through:

- http://conal.net/blog/posts/elegant-memoization-with-functional-memo-tries
- [How does Data.MemoCombinators work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980102/how-does-data-memocombinators-work)
- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie

But to make a long story short, memo tries in Haskell come out as lazily constructed, potentially infinite search trees where the value for each key is computed by applying the function that we're memoizing.

Memo tries may not be exactly what you're looking for, but there's a good chance the technique can be adapted to whatever your goal is.