# Using lazy evaluation to compute a numerical grid

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

let `f m x` be a computationally expensive function that takes two arguments and is computed using a numerical algorithm. `f` is a [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) function that has the property that the derivate of  `f m x` is equal to `f m+1 x`.

In order to lower the computational cost of calling this function thousand of times, we can expand it in a 6 terms Taylor series around `xk`,

```
f(m,x) = f(m,xk + dx) = f(m,xk) -f(m+1,xk)*dx + 0.5*f(m+2,xk)(dx)^2 - 1/6 * f(m+3,xk)(dx)^3 + 1/24 * f(m+4,xk)(dx)^4  + 1/120 * f(m+5,xk)(dx)^5......
```

Where `f(m+1,xk)` is the first derivate of `f m`.

Using the Taylor series we can generate a grid of `xk` points `[0.1, 0.2, ..xk,.. xmax]`  in `mmax + 6` dimesions, where `xmax` and `mmax` are the maximum value of `x` and `m`, respectively. Basically, the idea is to populate the nodes of the grid calling the expensive function `f` and the value of the function between nodes are calculated using the above Taylor series expansion.

This grid can be generated using a lazy map,

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>),(<*>))
import Data.Map.Lazy as M

data Fun = Fun Double Double deriving (Ord,Eq) -- data representing the point f m x 

generateGrid :: (Double -> Double -> Double)-> Int -> Int -> Double -> Map Fun Double
generateGrid f mMax xmax delta = M.fromList $ zip keys vals
  where keys = Fun <$> [fromIntegral x | x <- [0..mMax]] <*> [delta*fromIntegral(i) | i <- [0..xmax]]
        vals = fmap (\(Fun m x) -> f m x) keys

funTaylor :: Map Fun Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
funTaylor grid m x = (fun m xk) - (fun (m+1) xk)*dx + 0.5*(fun (m+2) xk)*dx^2 - 
(1/6)*(fun (m+3) xk)*dx^3 + (1/24)*(fun (m+4) xk)*dx^4 - (1/120)*(fun (m+5) xk)*dx^5
  where delta = 0.1
        dx    = x-xk
        xk    = (calcClosestPoint x )* delta
        fun   = calcutateFun grid  
        calcClosestPoint r = fromIntegral  $ floor $ x /delta

calculateFun :: Map Fun Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
calculateFun = ....
```

We have a grid where each node is a thunk of the expensive function `f`. Now every time that we need to calculate `f` we call `funTaylor` instead of `f`.

Notice that's this is a virtual grid in the sense that every time that we call `funTaylor m x`, only the points involved in the Taylor series are evaluated while the rest of the grid remains unevaluated.

Now suppose that I don't know *a priori* what are the number `xmax` and `mmax`, this virtual space is huge therefore guessing the limits and generating millions of thunks is not a good option.
The idea then is to be able to construct the grid "*on the fly*", every time that the funTaylor function is invocated new entries are added to the Map. The problem is that the `funTaylor` function is called from several parts in my code, from several functions that are evaluated in parallel. Then, I need to share the grid between all the functions that call `funTaylor`.

One alternative is to create a Channel or Queue that would work like a server between the grid and the functions that call `funTaylor`, every time a new value `funTaylor m x` is required it's sent to a Queue that update the grid avoiding the problem of sharing the State-grid between several functions.

The question is then:
What is the best way to generate the grid "*on the fly?*"

Comment: Don't worry about the structure of the grid, just [memoize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators-0.5.1/docs/Data-MemoCombinators.html)!  That library (and other memo libraries) memoize functions from integral types using an infinite tree described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980102/how-does-data-memocombinators-work).

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I find it a bit weird. What grid are you talking about? A list is not a grid. First of all, what kind of function is this really – I suppose `f :: Int -> Double -> Double` and the `m` parameter really just specifies that `f n` is the _n_-th derivative of `f 0`? Or is `m` actually another continuous parameter, which you want to cover in the grid?

Comment: `f m` is the *m-th* derivative of the function but also another parameter because I  want to calculate the `f 0 x`,  'f 1 x`, ... `f mmax` derivatives