# Memoize Project Euler 116 in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming

Below is my first attempt at this problem.  It is basically a transliteration of my C++ solution, minus a global hash table used to memoize the results of function f.

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f blocksize spaces
    | blocksize > spaces = 0
    | blocksize == spaces = 1
    | otherwise = 1 + fIter blocksize (spaces - blocksize)

fIter :: Int -> Int -> Int
fIter blocksize spaces =
    sum $ map (f blocksize) [1..spaces]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let spaces = 50
    print $ fIter 2 spaces + fIter 3 spaces + fIter 4 spaces
```

I think I understand the basic idea of creating a lazy data structure that is filled in as necessary, as in [this type of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976908/how-are-dynamic-programming-algorithms-implemented-in-idiomatic-haskell/4984168), but what's throwing me here is that there are two mutually-recursive functions that call each other rather than one.  I've tried combining them into one form, as below, but haven't had any luck getting it straight in my head yet.  Any tips?

```
fIter2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
fIter2 b s = sum $ map (\i -> memos ! i) [1..s]
    where
        memos = listArray (1, s) (map (f b) [1..s])
        f blocksize spaces
          | blocksize > spaces = 0
          | blocksize == spaces = 1
          | otherwise = 1 + fIter2 blocksize (spaces - blocksize)
```

(I'm aware that there is a combinatoric solution to this problem, but I'm more interested in getting better at dynamic programming in Haskell right now.)

Answer (score 4):

`f` is a very simple function. Assuming `fIter` is easy to compute, `f` will also be easy to compute. We don't need to memoize `f`. Our only goal will be to memoize `fIter`.

When starting to memoize a recursive function in Haskell, it's useful to write the function in open-recursive form. The open recursive form of a function removes explicit recursion and instead adds an extra argument for what to do when the function needs to call itself recursively. This will give us a way to change how the function recursively calls itself.

We'll change the signature of `fIter` from the first type to the second type

```
                      The type of fIter
                       v
                       Int -> Int -> Int
(Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
 ^                     ^
 |                     Gets back something with the type of fIter
 What to do when fIter needs to call itself recursively
```

`fIter` calls itself recursively through `f`, so we'll first add the `(Int -> Int -> Int)` argument for how to call `fIter` to `f`

```
f' :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
f' r blocksize spaces
    | blocksize > spaces = 0
    | blocksize == spaces = 1
    | otherwise = 1 + r blocksize (spaces - blocksize)
```

The modified `fIter'` will pass how to recursively call itself (that it got from the new argument) as the new argument to `f'`.

```
fIter' :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
fIter' r blocksize spaces =
    sum $ map (f' r blocksize) [1..spaces]
```

We can recover the original slow `fIter` by fixing it with `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` defined in [`Data.Function`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html) as `fix f = let x = f x in x`.

```
fIter :: Int -> Int -> Int
fIter = fix fIter'
```

Now we're in a good place to change how `fIter` calls itself. Another "lazy data structure that is filled in as necessary" is provided in `Data.MemoTrie` in the [MemoTrie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) package. It provides two functions that are interesting to us. `trie :: HasTrie a => (a -> b) -> a :->: b` builds a lazy data structure built from the supplied function. `untrie :: HasTrie a => (a :->: b) -> a -> b` returns a function that looks up the arguments from the lazy data structure. These only work for certain argument types `HasTrie a` for which a lazy data structure can be built. Fortunately for our problem there are already instances for `HasTrie Int` and `(HasTrie a, HasTrie b) => HasTrie (a, b)`.

`trie` from `Data.MemoTrie` only accepts a single argument, so we are going to need to pack the two arguments to `fIter` up in to a single argument. We'd normally do this with [`uncurry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:uncurry), but, since `fIter'` needs to take something with the same type as its result as an argument, we also need to [`curry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:curry) the recursive call to unpack the arguments. `uncurryOr` will uncurry any open recursive function.

```
uncurryOR :: (( a -> b  -> c) ->  a -> b  -> c) ->
              ((a,   b) -> c) -> (a,   b) -> c
uncurryOR or = uncurry . or . curry
```

Applying this to `fIter'` yields a satisfying result, `uncurryOR fIter' :: ((Int, Int) -> Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Int`.

To memoize an open recursive function in general, we build a trie for the open recursive function passing in trie lookup as how the function should get its recursive results.

```
import Data.MemoTrie

memoOR :: HasTrie a => ((a -> b) -> a -> b) ->
                                    a -> b
memoOR or = f
    where
        f = untrie t
        t = trie (or f)
```

We can write `memoOR` more elegantly in terms of `fix` and `memo = untrie . trie` from `Data.MemoTrie`.

```
memoOR or = fix (memo . or)
```

We can now define how to compute `fIter` efficiently

```
fIter :: Int -> Int -> Int
fIter = curry . memoOR .  uncurryOR $ fIter'
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I'm going to need a minute to digest it though.