# Haskell performance using dynamic programming

Tags: performance, haskell, dynamic-programming

I am attempting to calculate the Levenshtein distance between two strings using dynamic programming. This is being done through Hackerrank, so I have timing constraints. I used a techenique I saw in: [How are Dynamic Programming algorithms implemented in idiomatic Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976908/how-are-dynamic-programming-algorithms-implemented-in-idiomatic-haskell) and it seems to be working.  Unfortunaly, it is timing out in one test case.  I do not have access to the specific test case, so I don't know the exact size of the input.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.IArray
import Data.Array.Unboxed

main = do
  n <- readLn
  replicateM_ n $ do
    s1 <- getLine
    s2 <- getLine
    print $ editDistance s1 s2

editDistance :: String -> String -> Int
editDistance s1 s2 = dynamic editDistance' (length s1, length s2)
  where
    s1' :: UArray Int Char
    s1' = listArray (1,length s1) s1
    s2' :: UArray Int Char
    s2' = listArray (1,length s2) s2
    editDistance' table (i,j)
      | min i j == 0 = max i j
      | otherwise = min' (table!((i-1),j) + 1) (table!(i,(j-1)) + 1) (table!((i-1),(j-1)) + cost)
      where
        cost =  if s1'!i == s2'!j then 0 else 1
        min' a b = min (min a b)

dynamic :: (Array (Int,Int) Int -> (Int,Int) -> Int) -> (Int,Int) -> Int
dynamic compute (xBnd, yBnd) = table!(xBnd,yBnd)
  where
    table = newTable $ map (\coord -> (coord, compute table coord)) [(x,y) | x<-[0..xBnd], y<-[0..yBnd]]
    newTable xs = array ((0,0),fst (last xs)) xs
```

I've switched to using arrays, but that speed up was insufficient.  I cannot use Unboxed arrays, because this code relies on laziness. Are there any glaring performance mistakes I have made? Or how else can I speed it up?

Comment: Strings are very inefficient. For a competition program I would read the input in as a ByteString if you can get away with that - other use Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backward equations for edit distance calculations are:

```
f(i, j) = minimum [
  1 + f(i + 1, j), -- delete from the 1st string
  1 + f(i, j + 1), -- delete from the 2nd string 
  f(i + 1, j + 1) + if a(i) == b(j) then 0 else 1 -- substitute or match
]
```

So within each dimension, you need nothing more than the very *next* index: `+ 1`. This is a *sequential* access pattern, not random access to require arrays; and can be implemented using lists and nested right folds:

```
editDistance :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
editDistance a b = head . foldr loop [n, n - 1..0] $ zip a [m, m - 1..]
  where
  (m, n) = (length a, length b)
  loop (s, l) lst = foldr go [l] $ zip3 b lst (tail lst)
    where
    go (t, i, j) acc@(k:_) = inc `seq` inc:acc
      where inc = minimum [i + 1, k + 1, if s == t then j else j + 1]
```

You may test this code in [Hackerrank Edit Distance Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/cse-830-homework-3/challenges/edit-distance) as in:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad (replicateM_)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

editDistance :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
editDistance a b = ... -- as implemented above

main :: IO ()
main = do
  Just n <- readMaybe <$> getLine
  replicateM_ n $ do
    a <- getLine
    b <- getLine
    print $ editDistance a b
```

which passes all tests with a decent performance.