# Space leak in dynamic Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation, space-leak

I posted this question a few days ago: [Haskell performance using dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798956/haskell-performance-using-dynamic-programming) and was recommended to use ByteStrings instead of Strings.  After implementing the algorithm with ByteStrings, the program crashes, going over the memory limits.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array.IArray
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = do
  n <- readLn
  pairs <- replicateM n $ do
    s1 <- B.getLine
    s2 <- B.getLine
    return (s1,s2)
  mapM_ (print . editDistance) pairs

editDistance :: (B.ByteString, B.ByteString) -> Int
editDistance (s1, s2) = dynamic editDistance' (B.length s1, B.length s2)
  where
    editDistance' table (i,j)
      | min i j == 0 = max i j
      | otherwise = min' (table!((i-1),j) + 1) (table!(i,(j-1)) + 1) (table!((i-1),(j-1)) + cost)
      where
        cost =  if B.index s1 (i-1) == B.index s2 (j-1) then 0 else 1
        min' a b = min (min a b)

dynamic :: (Array (Int,Int) Int -> (Int,Int) -> Int) -> (Int,Int) -> Int
dynamic compute (xBnd, yBnd) = table!(xBnd,yBnd)
  where
    table = newTable $ map (\coord -> (coord, compute table coord)) [(x,y) | x<-[0..xBnd], y<-[0..yBnd]]
    newTable xs = array ((0,0),fst (last xs)) xs
```

The memory consumption appears to scale with `n`. The length of the input strings are 1000 characters.  I would expect Haskell to free all memory used in `editDistance` after each solution is printed.  Is this not the case? If not, how can I force this?

The only other real calculation I see is for `cost` but forcing that with `seq` did nothing.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem.  What version of GHC are you using? What flags are you compiling with?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson This is being done through a HackerRank contest.  The environment uses ghc 7.8 and only give 512 MB of memory. No flags as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Or perhaps I misunderstand your problem.  Certainly memory is obviously linear with `n` since you are reading `n` lines of strings from stdin before performing any operations.  Is that all or are you observing editDistance take too much memory over some dimension?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson The bulk of the memory usage is in the dynamic table that is constructed in editDistance.  It seems that I have enough room for 3-4 or these tables, since it will not crash for `n` less than 4.  But after one table is constructed, the answer can be pulled out and I will no longer need that table, but it seems to persist.

Comment: What evidence do you have for that diagnosis?  It seems to be an assumption. If the program crashes on `n>4` then perhaps that many input strings plus one table is too large.  Certainly with GHC 8.x I see the tables are GCed and things run in ~constant space modulo jitter during evaluation.  Have you considered an unboxed table?

Comment: Also, instead of forcing the entire list via `last` just use the value - you know it after all: `array ((0,0),(xBnd,yBnd)) xs`.  Notice the list is `strLen^2` length, so you are allocating a whole lot of memory only to free it a moment later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly your memory  will increase with `n` if you read all `n` inputs prior to computing any results and printing outputs.  You could try interleaving the input and output operations:

```
main = do
  n <- readLn
  replicateM_ n $ do
    s1 <- B.getLine
    s2 <- B.getLine
    print (editDistance (s1,s2))
```

Or alternatively using lazy IO (untested, probably needs gratuitous `B.`):

```
main = do
  n <- readLn
  cont <- getContents
  let lns = take n (lines cont)
      pairs = unfoldr (\case (x:y:rs) -> Just ((x,y),rs) ; _ -> Nothing) lns
  mapM_ (print . editDistance) pairs
```

EDIT: Other possible savings include using an unboxed array and not forcing your whole `strLen^2` size list via `last` during array construction.  Consider `array ((0,0),(xBnd,yBnd)) xs`.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that the problem is that your `min'` is not strict enough. Because it doesn't force its arguments it simply builds up a thunks for each array element. This causes more memory to be used, GC times to increase, etc.

I would try:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

...
min' !a !b !c = min a (min b c)
```